# .getContext is not a function ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, canvas, gsap

I'm trying to use GSAP to make a scrolling animation in my react application however I keep getting the error .getContext is not a function when I have linked it to the canvas.

my plan is to create a scrolling animation similar to a flip book sort of thing

any advice would be very much appreciated

thanks

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import gsap from "gsap";
import ScrollTrigger from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";

function Landing() {
  const canvasRef = useRef();
  canvasRef.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvasRef.height = window.innerHeight;
  const context = canvasRef.getContext("2d");
  const frameCount = 230;

  const currentFrame = (index) =>
    `../../assets/landing-animations/${(index + 1).toString()}.jpg`;
  const images = [];
  let ball = { frame: 0 };

  for (let i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = currentFrame(i);
    images.push(img);
  }

  images[0].onload = render;

  function render() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasRef.width, canvasRef.height);
    context.drawImage(images[ball.frame]);
  }
  return (
    <div className="landing">
      <h1 className="landing__header">Welcome to my portfolio</h1>
      <canvas className="landing__canvas" ref={canvasRef}></canvas>;
    </div>
  );
}

export default Landing;
```

Comment: try `canvasRef.current.getContext()`

Comment: **It's basically just a typo.** You want `canvasRef.current.getContext(/*...*/);` It's a method of the canvas, not the ref. The current value of the ref is on the `current` property.

Comment: Separately: You can't use the element until it exists, which it doesn't immediately after your `useRef` call. You need to wait for the component to mount, via `useEffect`.

Answer (score 2):

Need to access the `current` since the reference to the node becomes accessible at the current attribute of the ref.

Additionally wrap this with `useMemo` to detect changes to canvasRef

```
const context = useMemo(() => canvasRef?.current.getContext("2d"), [canvasRef])
```

Comment: Recommend adding a bit of context to this answer: what is `current`? Why memoize?

Comment: @Nick added some context

Comment: I replaced my context variable with yours and also imported useMemo, however now I get the error cannot read properties of getContext

Answer (score 1):

You need to add .current to access the .getContext

```
canvasRef.current.getContext("2d")
```

Try to add useEffect and see the results

```
 useEffect(()=>{
     if(!!canvasRef){
       console.log(canvasRef.current.getContext("2d"))
     }
 },[canvasRef])
```

Comment: i have tried this however now I'm getting the error:  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getContext')

Comment: You need to check if the ref is not equal null.

Comment: my console logs show that the ref is equal to the canvas

Comment: actually it is equal to my canvas and undefined at the same time

Comment: You can try the solution that i provide with useEffect

Comment: @Omar One variable can't be equal to two different values "at the same time"

Comment: good mention @Omar variable can't be equal to two different values "at the same time"

Comment: sorry yes you're right it is coming up as undefined